# Typescript get object property type from name

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to do a type inference function in typescript inside a reactive bus class.

Here is an example:

```
  // This is the function
  getValue<T>(data: T, key: keyof T) {
    return data[key];
  }

  // This is the test
  interface IState {
    field1: number;
    field2: string;
  }

  const state: IState = {
    field1: 123,
    field2: 'abc'
  };

  const x = getValue(state, 'field1');
```

Key variable is infered succesfully (i cannot type different values than interface keys).
The problem is that doing this the type of 'x' variable is number|string but i'm expecting number.

Am i missing something? Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `getValue` has inferred return type of `T[keyof T]`, which is `number|string`.

What you want can be achieved the following way:

```
function getValue<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T, key: K) {
  return data[key];
}

// This is the test
interface IState {
  field1: number;
  field2: string;
}

const state: IState = {
  field1: 123,
  field2: 'abc'
};

const x = getValue(state, 'field1');
```

This way, the return type of `getValue` is `T[K]`, where `K` is inferred to be one specific key in `keyof T`.

Comment: This only seems to work when the field name is directly given but not when it comes from elsewhere, e.g.: `['field1', 'field2'].map(field => getValue(state, field))` complains that `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof IState'.`