# How to use `some` to partially check items in object using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, keyof

I have an object:

```
interface MYInterface {
  aaa: number;
  bbb: number;
  ccc?: number | undefined;
}

const myObject: MYInterface = {
  aaa: 0,
  bbb: 0,
  ccc: 132,
};
```

I want to check if some keys in this object, satisfy a condition! I'm using Array.some(...) like below:

```
const res = ['aaa', 'bbb'].some((key) => myObject[key] > 0)
```

but for `myObject[key]` I'm getting a TypeScript error about:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'INxStateCounts'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'INxStateCounts'.
```

I know that what am I trying to do is checking array of strings (keys) with objects but my array contains those keys in string.

I have tried to cast key  as `keyof MYInterface` but no luck! I was getting so many other errors. How can I fix this?

Also my object is very big, here I use 3 properties to demonstrate the issue.

[Just in case if you want to test](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE0CS5rycgbwChlk5yAuZEAVwFsAjaAbhOQY6tsZbYX4D8XekyjIAPshogAJhBigIM1gF8iCAPYgAzmGR0AngHkGAKwgIwVDNkixEKALyE25OFQAMAGjYcGnn1J%20BCoARgBmACYfFVZ1LV1kKAhtZGcAbQByN0yvZEy-TIBdADptDToIAAoqgGsIAwBKNIA%20fWMzCzB0%20oMi5DaPRqA).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript get object property type from name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974875/typescript-get-object-property-type-from-name)

Comment: how can i use it with `some(...)`? That is where i stuck tbh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make more concrete typing in your code, like this:

```
function someOf<T>(keys: (keyof T)[], obj: T): boolean {
  return keys.some((key) => obj[key] > 0)
}

const res = someOf(['aaa', 'bbb'], myObject);
```

Comment: what is the typeof T when you calling function like `someOf(['aaa', 'bbb'], myObject)`?

Comment: My understanding is `MYInterface`, and i should call it like `someOf<MYInterface>(['aaa', 'bbb'], myObject)`

Comment: why extracting it into function does not give you error? but having it in one line does?  why i still getting error with this: `(['aaa', 'bbb'] as (keyof MYInterface)[]).some(key => (myObject as MYInterface)[key] > 0)`

Comment: There is a simple reason for that, you have optional property `ccc` and it can be undefined. When it's inside the function, generic typing doesn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```
const keys : Array<keyof MYInterface> = ['aaa', 'bbb']

const res = keys.some((key) => (myObject[key] !== undefined && myObject[key]! > 0))
```

for some reason the bang `!` operator is needed despite `undefined` checking.

Comment: actually thanks for your answer, but I don't want to use that (!), because I need to assure the correct type

Comment: The `!` operator assert that `myObject[key]` is not null/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you use object index signature you might get what you are looking for. Try:

```
interface MYInterface {
  [key:string]: number;
}
...
```

Other ways to approach this: [How to dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript](https://blog.logrocket.com/dynamically-assign-properties-object-typescript/#solution-1-explicitly-type-object-declaration-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `as const` to make it a tuple type. Then, the type of `key` argument will become `'aaa'|'bbb'` instaed of string/any.

```
const res = (['aaa', 'bbb'] as const).some((key) => myObject[key] > 0)
```